# How to list automorphisms on a finite set and analyze them

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, assignment

Let `s` be a finite set of integer lattice points, for example `s = { {0,0} , {0,3} , {1,1} , {0,2} }`.

I am trying to do two things:

1. Create a list of all the automorphisms on `s`. That is, if $s$ is our set, I want to list all onto functions $f:s \rightarrow s$, not including duplicates. (Consider $f$ and $g$ duplicates if for each point in $s$, that point is taken by $f$ and $g$ to the same point.)
2. Among the automorphisms, find those $f$ for which `Condition[ x , f[x] ]` is `True` for all `x` in `s`.

Here, `Condition` is just an aribtrary function that takes in two $2$-tuples and returns `True` or `False`.

I am trying to do (1) to accomplish (2). But, I have never tried to handle lists of functions before, and am not sure how to do it in Mathematica. I am trying to do this by treating a 'function' as a collection of $2$-tuples of $2$-tuples, where the second element is the target of the function acting on the first. But this is very, very, tedious, and I am hoping there is a better way.

Comment: I think you can find a group that is isomorphic to `s` and calculate its [automorphism group](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/403) with the help of [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it simple, I choose a set of symbols (you can replace them with points in 1,2,3.. n dimensions):

```
sym = Array[Subscript[s, #] &, 4]
```

We get all automorphism by Permutations[sym]. A permutation gives the image of the first element, the second element ...

```
automorph= Permutations[sym]
```

Finally to pick all automorphism that fulfill some predicate "pred" we can use "Select". E.g. to get all automorphism that leave the first 2 elements in place we define the predicate:

```
pred[x_] := x[[1]] === sym[[1]] && x[[2]] === sym[[2]]
```

Or all together:

```
sym = Array[Subscript[s, #] &, 4];
automorph = Permutations[sym];
pred[x_] := x[[1]] === sym[[1]] && x[[2]] === sym[[2]]
Select[automorph, pred]
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'step-by-step'.  Very helpful.

Comment: Your answer is great. What is the automorphism group of the symmetric group `S4`? Is it `S4`?

Comment: Yes indeed. See e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups